# How do I grab each instance of a tag in Node?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, substring

I'm trying to write a script in Node.js that will import a text document. The text contains three newspaper articles with a number of metadata tags. I need to grab the contents for two of those tags for each article, and put that in an array or JSON file or something.

For instance, one of the tag pairs is `<text></text>` which contains the full text of the article. Another one is `<docid></docid>` which contains a unique number for each article. Preferably my array would end up looking something like like

```
articles = [[docid1, text1], [docid2, text2], [docid3, text3]]
```

or maybe as a JSON file styled like

```
{"article1" : {"docid" : "docid1", "text" : "text1"}
 "article2" : {"docid" : "docid2", "text" : "text2"}
}
```

Using `substring` and `search()` I can get the contents of the first article, using the following code:

```
var substring = string.substring(string.search("<text>"), string.search("</text>"))
```

But I don't need just the first article, but the contents of each instance where there's a pair of `<text> </text>` tags.

Can I use `search()` to find more than one result and stuff it in an array?

The text is formatted like this. It's similar to html but I don't think it's proper html.:

```xml
<doc>
<docid> 1 </docid>
<date>
January 1, 2000 
</date>
<headline>
SOMETHING HAS HAPPENED IN THE WORLD 
</headline>
<byline>
By Andy N. Onymous. 
</byline>
<text>
Blah blah this is text blah blah lorum ipsum dolor sit amet. 
</text>
</doc>
```

Comment: I would go for the clean approach with streams: create a ReadStream to read your textfile, pipe this through one or more Transform streams that extract the info between your tags, and finally use a WriteStream to store the result in a file, or a new string.

Comment: What is the format of the text file.  It is HTML or XML?

Comment: What is the format of the text in the text file?  That's what we need to know.  HTML?  XML?  Something custom?  Please show us a sample of the data.  How can you expect us to answer a question on how to parse it without showing us the actual format of the data?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! I added an example of what it's formatted like to my question. It's similar to html but wouldn't work as an html page on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out! I had to use the `substring`-approach within a for loop to get the docid and text for each document and put those in an array. It's probably not the cleanest approach, but streams are giving me nightmares and this works for me! The code is:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var collection = fs.readFileSync('collection.txt').toString();

var articles = collection.split('</doc>');
var articleCount = articles.length-1
var articleArray = [];

for (var i=0; i < articleCount; i++) {
    articleArray[i] = [articles[i].substring(articles[i].search('<docid>')+7, articles[i].search('</docid>')), articles[i].substring(articles[i].search('<text>')+6, articles[i].search('</text>'))];
    } 

    console.log(articleArray[1]);
```